# Frontpage grid - Rowsize to big

Tags: views

Following configuration: Drupal 7.31 / Theme: Tb Corpal (based on nucleus 7.x-1.5)

I am using views to configurate what is shown on the frontpage. Format is "Grid".

Please have a look at the page: www.reatch.ch

You will notice, that the first three teasers are shown right below the slideshow. Then there is a huge vertical gap to the fourth teaser. After the fourth teaser there is another huge vertical gap to the footer.

I am not sure why this happens. Did not find an option in views which enabled to change that... Please let me know what other information you need to answer this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow.. that min-height is a doozy.  The only place I can find where it is located is inside one of the theme's javascript files **jquery.matchHeights.min.js**.

I did not buy that theme so I do not know the configuration files, however, see if there is a place in admin where you can disable the **Match Heights Plugin** file.

Comment: OK, I just uncommented all the code in this js plugin. Et voilà! The strange vertical gap is gone! Now, how can I find out if this js plugin is maybe needed somewhere? (And doing something usefull)

Comment: Yey!  It seemed to simply make sure that all the teaser blocks end up being the same height.  I would think that being uneven might cause float issues in some browsers. Although since they are wrapped in a "row" div, I wouldn't think this would be an issue!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the system is tossing in an unusual min-height value for each div.  Can you locate this in your code:  div class="grid-inner col-inner clearfix" style="min-height: 2694px;"
You might have to work your CSS to get it all formatted properly.  If you remove that min-height variable, it formats correctly (in FireFox)